# nginx1.8.0+PHP 5.6.16 on OSX, some php pages links show 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

My page documents locate in `/usr/local/var/www` `drwxr-xr-x joshua:admin`
My nginx configure is [nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/chinanoahli/8c0f75319e8ef0606381) and my php and php-fpm configure is [this file](https://gist.github.com/chinanoahli/d91acaa041b2c5635bdd)

and I find I can use wordpress(/usr/local/var/www/wordpress) perfectly, but not anchor(/usr/local/var/www/anchor), anchor will shows 500 error.

I get this log from the php-fpm

```
NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
```

I already tried make the php-fpm.conf file like this

```
user = joshua
group = admin
listen.owner = joshua
listen.group = admin
```

but nothing happened, and the error log still the **same**.

Is there any ways can make it work when FPM is **not** running as root, because I dont realy want FPM run as root.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure which user launched master PHP-FPM process, not pool processes.

for example:

> root@strangeman:# ps aux | grep php-fpm
>
> **root**      1135  0.0  1.6 334196 16812 ?        Ss   Dec13   0:02 php-fpm: **master process** (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)

This user may be declared in php-fpm startup script

Comment: I tried a lot, but I still don't know how to launch PHP-FPM as root. Normally, if the `/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php56.plist` owner by root the PHP-FPM should launch as root, but it still launch as normal user on my mac. I really don't know how to get it work. My `homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist` and `homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist` can launch as root by changing this two files to onwer by root.